# Set UMASK value only for non root users

Tags: linux, shell, umask

I want to set the UMASK value for non root users as 077 and for the root users it should be 022.

I have changed the UMASK value in `/etc/login.defs` from 022 to 077. But this seems to change the UMASK of my root user as well. Is there a way in which I can only change the UMASK value of new non-root users that are created?

Note: I need to be able to do this in a script.

Comment: Questions like this are better suited to [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put `umask 022` in your root's `.profile`/`.bashrc` and have 077 as a default in your `/etc/login.defs`.

The `umask` shell builtin makes the `umask` system call which sets  process-inheritable the `umask` property: a umask call set in one process affects all descendants of that process (unless they themselves make a `umask` call), so to set a `umask` for "user", you need to call `umask` in a process from which all user processes descend (the login shell and/or the shell through which `sudo` commands are invoked).

Comment: Thanks! I have done what you have suggested and it works. I found out that the actual issue was arising due to `USERGROUPS_ENAB` being set to `yes`. This makes `077` -> `007`.